# Failed to find target with hash string '27.0.3' Android Studio 3.1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After updating android studio I am facing `Failed to find target with hash string '27.0.3' in: /Users/duggu/Library/Android/sdk`.

**Gradle**

[image]

**SDK Manager**

**SDK Platforms**

[image]

**SDK Tools**

[image]

**SDK folder look like below**

[image]

[image]

I tried so many links but didn't not achieve my goal yet :-

[failed to find target with hash string android-23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417537/failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-23)

[Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-N'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197969/cause-failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-n)

[Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'N'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985657/cause-failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-n)

[Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-N'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197969/cause-failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-n)

Comment: see this hope it help you https://forums.bignerdranch.com/t/failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-26-in/13827

Comment: also whatch this guy https://youtu.be/UejZDAjeILM

Comment: @ALTegani already tried

Answer (score 0):

My mistake is as follows

```
compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
```

This is a **Copy** caused error， Correct as follows

```
compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
```

The compileSdk version is the android version, not the buildtools version.